# How to find all possible path to destination?

Tags: matlab, path, matlab-figure

The clusterhead is already selected based on the distance value. However there is a problem to make connect a node to the clusterhead. I want to make a path from 4-9-1-3-5-CH, another route is 8-9-1-3-5-CH, 10-2-CH and 7-CH.

```
if true
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    clc;
    clear all;
    N=10;               % No of nodes
    data = rand(N,2);   % Randomly generated n no. of nodes
    x = data(:,1)*100;
    y = data(:,2)*100;
    numEdge = 19;
    plot(x,y,'rx');
    node=struct('id',{},'x',{},'y',{},'dist',{},'link',{'1'});
    for i=1:N
        node(i).id=i;
        node(i).x=x(i);
        node(i).y=y(i);
        text(x(i),y(i),num2str(i));
    end
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % CH
    ch1=ceil(rand(1)*N);
    text(node(ch1).x,node(ch1).y,['CH'],'Color' ,'b');
    for  i = 1:N
        node(i).dist = sqrt(((node(ch1).x - node(i).x)^2 + (node(ch1).y - node(i).y)^2));
        a(i)=node(i).dist;
        disp(node(i).dist);
    end
    A=sort(a,'descend');
    a=1;
    for i = 1:N
        node_distance(a) = node(i).dist;
        a = a+1;
    end
    Maximum_distance = max(node_distance);
    for i = 1:N
        if node(i).dist == max(node_distance)
            next_header = node(i).id;
        end
    end
end
```

The Result:

[image: The result-figure1]

Accepted result:

[image: acceptedResult-figure2]

How to make a connection between node to the clusterhead? Any function or clue for me?

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a line in the figure? Did you try `line`?

Comment: I try to make a connection between node. For example: 4-9-1-3-5-CH, another route is 8-9-1-3-5-CH, 10-2-CH and 7-CH.